# cant delete record from database using $.ajax() function

Tags: php, jquery

i have list of records. i have delete button with every record and i am deleting record with `$.ajax()` function. but when i click on the delete button it does not delete the record from database , and when i alert data it outputs whole html page.here is code below. please help me.

**html code**

```
<tbody>
      <tr class="gradeX odd">
        <td class="sorting_1">2</td>
        <td class=" ">test</td>
        <td class=" ">test</td>
        <td class="center ">0</td>
        <td class="center ">Active</td>
        <td class=" "><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle" name="editRecord"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-default btn-circle" id="2" name="deleteRecord"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="gradeX even">
        <td class="sorting_1">3</td>
        <td class=" ">sarees</td>
        <td class=" ">contains sarres</td>
        <td cl="center ">1</td>
        <td class="center ">Active</td>
        <td class=" "><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle" name="editRecord"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-default btn-circle" id="3" name="deleteRecord"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button></td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
```

**jquery**

```
$(document.body).on('click', '[name="deleteRecord"]', function(){
     var id= $(this).attr('id');
     var parent = $(this).parent().parent();
      if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this row?"))
        {
         $.ajax({
                   type: "GET",
                   url: "admin_operation.php?mode=delete_category&id="+id,
                   cache: false,

                   success: function(data)
                   { 
                    alert(data);
                    parent.fadeOut('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});
                   }
             });
        }
   });
```

**php code**

```
 $mode = $_GET['mode'];

 if($mode!='add_category' || $_GET['mode']!= "delete_category")
 {
     header('location:dashboard.php');
     die;

  }


    if($mode=='delete_category')
    {    

       $id=$_GET['id'];
       $q=$db->query("DELETE FROM db_category WHERE category_id='".$id."'");
       if($q){ echo "yes";}
       else{ echo "no";}

    }
```

Comment: What you're doing here is *really* dangerous. Firstly, anyone could delete stuff via that URL and secondly, you're wide open to SQL injection.

Comment: @marty but using post method , im getting the same error. what should i do ?

Comment: `POST` isn't going to prevent either of those two things.

Comment: Let's ignore the fact that this script is very dangerous, I think the problem is because it's looking for a string category_id (category_id='".$id."') while it should be looking for an integer (category_id=".$id.").

Comment: @user3288891, not sure what error is, but, for protection - before query, at the start of .php file, check if admin is logged in, and also check var id, before you insert it in the query.

Comment: Please first check u find out id or not. user class instead of name

Comment: @Marty then what should be the best option to prevent sql injection ?

Comment: Use [`prepared statements`](http://au1.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), though that will only resolve the second problem I mentioned.

Comment: DB backend should return error, when it fails. Read in the documentation how to fetch it and this should help you a lot. If you still will not know how to fix the problem, paste the error into your question.

Comment: @Marty I knew about `prepared statements` but just curious about the first problem. What do you means here and how to prevent it?

Comment: I mean if I visit `http://yoursite.com/admin_operation.php?mode=delete&id=X` I can delete records from your database. You prevent it with some type of authentication (e.g. checking if you're logged in as an administrator).

Comment: on the top of the page i have put this and in alert data is shows dashboard.php.

Comment: if($mode!='add_category' || $_GET['mode']!= "delete_category")
 {
     header('location:dashboard.php');
  die;
   
  }

Comment: @Marty i have updated php code , when i alert data in $.ajax function it returns whole dashboard.php page.

Comment: @user3288891 You have to do `exit` before the ending `}` of `if ($mode=='delete_category') {`

Comment: @RahilWazir but it alert whole dashboard.php page when i alert data in jquery , which runs before if ($mode=='delete_category') .

Comment: @user3288891 Please show us your full PHP code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You send  'url: "admin_operation.php?**mode=delete_category**&id="+id,' in javascript.
And, in php script you have a condition that rewrite headers and exit script.

```
if($mode!='add_category' || $_GET['mode']!= "**delete_category**")
{
    header('location:dashboard.php');
    die;
}
```

The next block of code

```
if($mode=='delete_category')
{
    // ...
}
```

never is reached.
Hope this helps you as solution.

Comment: tnx.. it should be && instead of ||
if($mode!='add_category' &&| $_GET['mode']!= "**delete_category**")